# Why does PHP/WordPress on IIS Express keep redirecting all requests to a different port?

Tags: wordpress, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm using Web Platform Installer and WebMatrix to set up a WordPress site running locally (Windows 7 Professional). It's the first time I've ever used WordPress and the first time I've ever used WebMatrix, so it's possible I'm missing something really basic.

Several times, I've had a problem where I hit 'Run' in WebMatrix. It opens the browser pointing to the correct URL - `http://localhost:10268/` - thinks for a second or two, and then redirects to a different port - in this case, `http://localhost:52925/` - which returns 'This web page is not available'

I have absolutely no idea where that second port is coming from, or why it's redirecting. I've searched the IIS Express config files (`C:\Users\dylan.beattie\Documents\IISExpress`) and the source code of my WordPress project, but can't find that port number `52925` anywhere.

Is this a built-in PHP / WordPress thing? Some sort of security feature, maybe? I'm completely stumped. One slightly odd detail - that may well be unrelated - is that I think this only happens after I start using revision control. The site will work fine when it's first created, but then when I open it from GitHub, things start going weird. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. It looks like there's a setting in WordPress that needs to match the IIS Express configuration - and when you check out a site via revision control or set up a new site from an existing folder in WebMatrix, it doesn't use the same IIS Express settings. In my case, I'd downloaded the code **and restored the database** from work I'd done earlier on a different machine, and so ended up with IIS listening on port 10268, but the WordPress site configured to listen on port 52925.

The IIS settings are in `C:\Users\user.name\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`, and the WordPress options are records in the `wp_options` table where `option_name` == 'siteurl' or 'home'

Two ways to fix it that I've found:

1. In WebMatrix, Site, Settings, change the site URL to wherever you're being redirected to.
2. Edit the `wp_options` table and change the settings to match the URL in WebMatrix/IISExpress.